# Can jqGrid summary footer be populated without userdata server request?

Tags: jqgrid, footer, summary, user-data

I have poured through every question asked on this website related to populating the jqGrid summary footer WITHOUT the userdata being a server request. And the jqGrid wiki resource and just cannot find an answer. Is this possible to do?

I use the jqGrid in many typical ways as part of my admin portal but have one particular use where I want the look & feel of the jqGrid to start out as an empty UI container of sorts for some user interaction adding rows through a form which doesn't post on Submit (thanks to Oleg's great script below) but simply adds the row and updates the summary footer with the values from the newly added row. I have 'summarytype:"sum"' in the colModel, "grouping:true", footerrow: true, userDataOnFooter: true, altRows: true, in the grid options but apart from the initial values supplied by the userdata in the local data string, the summary footer values never change. It seems like no one wants to touch this subject. Is it because the primary nature of the jqGrid is it's database driven functionality? I use about 15 instances of the jqGrid in it's database driven stance (many of which are in a production service now) but need to use it for consistency sake (all my UI's are inside jqTabs) initially as a client side UI with no server request (everything will be saved later to db) but I am pulling my hair out trying to manipulate the summary footer programmatically on and by the client only. Can anyone suggest how to cause values to the summary footer to update when a new row is added the values of which would be summed up with any existing rows and which does not involve any posting to server, just updates inside the grid?

The code supplied is kind of long and based primarily on user Oleg's solution for adding a row from a modal form without posting to the server. I've changed the local array data to JSON string simply to better understand the notation as I'm used to xml. The jsonstring initializes the grid with one default row for the user to edit. I've left out the jsonReader because the grid would not render with it.

In a nutshell then what I want to do is to have the summary footer update when a new row is added to the grid (no posting to server occurring at this point) or edited or deleted. When a certain set of values is achieved the user is prompted by a displayed button to save row data to db.

```
var lastSel, mydata = { "total": 1, "page": 1, "records": 1, "rows": [{ "id": acmid, "cell": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]}], "userdata":{ "mf": 0.00, "af":0.00,"pf":0.00,"cf":0.00 }}

grid = $("#ta_form_d"),
    onclickSubmitLocal = function (options, postdata) {

        var grid_p = grid[0].p,
            idname = grid_p.prmNames.id,
            grid_id = grid[0].id,
            id_in_postdata = grid_id + "_id",
            rowid = postdata[id_in_postdata],
            addMode = rowid === "_empty",
            oldValueOfSortColumn;

        // postdata has row id property with another name. we fix it:
        if (addMode) {
            // generate new id
            var new_id = grid_p.records + 1;
            while ($("#" + new_id).length !== 0) {
                new_id++;
            }
            postdata[idname] = String(new_id);
            //alert(postdata[idname]);
        } else if (typeof (postdata[idname]) === "undefined") {
            // set id property only if the property not exist
            postdata[idname] = rowid;
        }

        delete postdata[id_in_postdata];

        // prepare postdata for tree grid
        if (grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
            if (addMode) {
                var tr_par_id = grid_p.treeGridModel === 'adjacency' ? grid_p.treeReader.parent_id_field : 'parent_id';
                postdata[tr_par_id] = grid_p.selrow;
            }

            $.each(grid_p.treeReader, function (i) {
                if (postdata.hasOwnProperty(this)) {
                    delete postdata[this];
                }
            });
        }

        // decode data if there encoded with autoencode
        if (grid_p.autoencode) {
            $.each(postdata, function (n, v) {
                postdata[n] = $.jgrid.htmlDecode(v); // TODO: some columns could be skipped
            });
        }

        // save old value from the sorted column
        oldValueOfSortColumn = grid_p.sortname === "" ? undefined : grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, grid_p.sortname);
        //alert(oldValueOfSortColumn);
        // save the data in the grid
        if (grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
            if (addMode) {
                grid.jqGrid("addChildNode", rowid, grid_p.selrow, postdata);
            } else {
                grid.jqGrid("setTreeRow", rowid, postdata);
            }
        } else {

           if (addMode) {
                grid.jqGrid("addRowData", rowid, postdata, options.addedrow);


            } else {
                grid.jqGrid("setRowData", rowid, postdata);
            }
        }

        if ((addMode && options.closeAfterAdd) || (!addMode && options.closeAfterEdit)) {
            // close the edit/add dialog
            $.jgrid.hideModal("#editmod" + grid_id,
                              { gb: "#gbox_" + grid_id, jqm: options.jqModal, onClose: options.onClose });
        }

        if (postdata[grid_p.sortname] !== oldValueOfSortColumn) {
            // if the data are changed in the column by which are currently sorted
            // we need resort the grid
            setTimeout(function () {
                grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true}]);
            }, 100);
        }

        // !!! the most important step: skip ajax request to the server
        this.processing = true;
        return {};



    },

    editSettings = {
        //recreateForm:true,
        jqModal: false,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        savekey: [true, 13],
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
    },

    addSettings = {
        //recreateForm:true,
        jqModal: false,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        savekey: [true, 13],
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
    },

    delSettings = {
        // because I use "local" data I don't want to send the changes to the server
        // so I use "processing:true" setting and delete the row manually in onclickSubmit
        onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
            var grid_id = grid[0].id,
                grid_p = grid[0].p,
                newPage = grid[0].p.page;

            // delete the row
            grid.delRowData(rowid);
            $.jgrid.hideModal("#delmod" + grid_id,
                              { gb: "#gbox_" + grid_id, jqm: options.jqModal, onClose: options.onClose });

            if (grid_p.lastpage > 1) {// on the multipage grid reload the grid
                if (grid_p.reccount === 0 && newPage === grid_p.lastpage) {
                    // if after deliting there are no rows on the current page
                    // which is the last page of the grid
                    newPage--; // go to the previous page
                }
                // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
                grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: newPage}]);
            }

            return true;
        },
        processing: true
    };         //,
    /*initDateEdit = function (elem) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                autoSize: true,
                showOn: 'button', // it dosn't work in searching dialog
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                showWeek: true
            });
            //$(elem).focus();
        }, 100);
    },
    initDateSearch = function (elem) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                autoSize: true,
                //showOn: 'button', // it dosn't work in searching dialog
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                showWeek: true
            });
            //$(elem).focus();
        }, 100);
    };*/

    //jQuery("#ta_form_d").jqGrid({
    grid.jqGrid({
        // url:'/admin/tg_cma/ta_allocations.asp?acmid=' + acmid + '&mid=' + merchantid + '&approval_code=' + approval_code,
        //datatype: "local",
        //data: mydata,
        datatype: 'jsonstring',
        datastr: mydata,

        colNames: ['ID', 'Monthly Fees', 'ATM Fees', 'POS Fees', 'Card to Card Fees'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 90, align: "center", editable: true, editoptions: { size: 25 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 1, label: "EzyAccount ID", elmprefix: "(*) " }, editrules: { required: true} },
        { name: 'mf', index: 'mf', width: 130, align: "right", formatter: 'number', editable: true, summaryType: 'sum', editoptions: { size: 25 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 1, label: "Monthly Fee", elmprefix: "(*) " }, editrules: { required: true} },
        { name: 'af', index: 'af', width: 130, align: "right", formatter: 'number', editable: true, summaryType: 'sum', editoptions: { size: 25 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 1, label: "ATM Fee", elmprefix: "(*) " }, editrules: { required: true} },
        { name: 'pf', index: 'pf', width: 130, align: "right", formatter: 'number', editable: true, summaryType: 'sum', editoptions: { size: 25 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 4, colpos: 1, label: "POS Fee", elmprefix: "(*) " }, editrules: { required: true} },
        { name: 'cf', index: 'cf', width: 130, align: "right", formatter: 'number', editable: true, summaryType: 'sum', editoptions: { size: 25 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 5, colpos: 1, label: "Card to Card Fee", elmprefix: "(*) " }, editrules: { required: true} }
    ],
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        pager: '#pta_form_d',
        toolbar: [true, "top"],
        width: 500,
        height: 100,
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        multiselect: false,
        cellEdit: false,
        caption: "Allocations",
        grouping: true,
        /*groupingView: { 
            groupField: ['id', 'mf', 'af', 'pf', 'cf'],
            groupColumnShow: [true],
            groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>'],
            groupCollapse: false,
            groupOrder: ['asc'],
            groupSummary: [true],
            groupDataSorted: true 
        },*/
        footerrow: true,
        userDataOnFooter: true,
        altRows: true,
        ondblClickRow: function (rowid, ri, ci) {
            var p = grid[0].p;
            if (p.selrow !== rowid) {
                // prevent the row from be unselected on double-click
                // the implementation is for "multiselect:false" which we use,
                // but one can easy modify the code for "multiselect:true"
                grid.jqGrid('setSelection', rowid);
            }
            grid.jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid, editSettings);
        },
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
                // jqGrid hold intern savedRow array inside of jqGrid object,
                // so it is safe to call restoreRow method with any id parameter
                // if jqGrid not in editing state
                if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                    grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
                }
                lastSel = id;
            }
        },
        afterEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
            alert(iCol);
        },
        gridComplete: function () {

        },
        loadComplete: function (data) {


        }

    })
.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pta_form_d', {}, editSettings, addSettings, delSettings,
          { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false,
              onClose: function (form) {
                  // if we close the search dialog during the datapicker are opened
                  // the datepicker will stay opened. To fix this we have to hide
                  // the div used by datepicker
                  //$("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
              }
          });

$("#t_ta_form_d").append("<input type='button' class='add' value='Add New Allocation' style='height:20px; color:green; font-size:11px;' />");
$("input.add", "#t_ta_form_d").click(function () {
    jQuery("#ta_form_d").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", {
        //recreateForm:true,
        jqModal: false,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        savekey: [true, 13],
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal


    })
})
```

Comment: Referring to an answer by Stackoverflow user @Oleg  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128837/json-and-jqgrid-what-is-userdata) regarding `userdata` it is stated: _A standard JSON reader is defined so, that it read data userdata property from the root of data sent and just save it. This data is accessible with respect of:_ `var myUserData = jQuery("grid_id").getGridParam('userData');` Question then  can `userdata` be modified and retrieved after that initial read by jsonReader (using json for this example) and if so how can that locally modified `userdata` display in summary footer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case of "local" datatype one can use [footerData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method to set (or get) the data in the footer. Additionally the method [getCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) can be used co calculate the sum of elements in the column.

Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121350/jqgrid-access-cell-data-while-it-is-being-edited/5129908#5129908) for more information. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: at the moment this has resolved the problem and has supplied the behaviour I've been trying to achieve. Thanks a million for your prompt attention to this your knowledge in this area is very impressive.  Oh and thanks for saving my marriage too.